# How to add a space after every character in a string in php?

Tags: php, whitespace

I have a string in php named **$password**="**1bsdf4**";

I want output **"1 b s d f 4"**

How is it possible. I was trying implode function but i was not able to do..

```
$password="1bsdf4";    
$formatted = implode(' ',$password);    
echo $formatted;
```

I tried this code:

```
$str=array("Hello","User");    
$formatted = implode(' ',$str);    
echo $formatted;
```

Its working and adding space in hello and user !
Final Output I got **Hello User**

Thanks, yours answers will be appreciated.. :)

Comment: `$password="1bsdf4";    
$formatted = implode(' ', str_split($password));    
echo $formatted;`

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You can use implode you just need to use str_split first which converts the string to an array:

```
$password="1bsdf4";    
$formatted = implode(' ',str_split($password));
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php

Sorry didn't see your comment @MarkBaker if you want to convert you comment to an answer I can remove this.

Answer (score 10):

You can use [`chunk_split()`](http://www.php.net/chunk_split) for this purpose.

```
$formatted = trim(chunk_split($password, 1, ' '));
```

`trim` is necessary here to remove the whitespace after the last character.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer since `chunk_split()` takes about 40% less time to compute than the `implode(str_split())` method marked as "accepted".
*(tested on 3100 cases with PHP 7.3.25)

Comment: I agree this is way faster (more like 70% faster by my benchmark), but the accepted answer still only took .9 seconds on 1 million 32 character strings and to me it's a bit more readable.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code [[DEMO]](http://ideone.com/YIebCl):

```
<?php
 $password="1bsdf4";
 echo chunk_split($password, 1, ' ');
```

[chunk_split()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.chunk-split.php) is build-in PHP function for splitting string into smaller chunks.

Comment: The only issue for this solution is that adds an extra space at the end of the generated string.

Answer (score 0):

How about this one

```
$formatted = preg_replace("/(.)/i", "\${1} ", $formatted);
```

according to: http://bytes.com/topic/php/answers/882781-add-whitespace-between-letters

Comment: Though it works, regexes are a bit slow, alternative methods with native string functions are better

Answer (score 0):

This also Worked..

```
$password="1bsdf4";    
echo $newtext = wordwrap($password, 1, "\n", true);
```

Output: **"1 b s d f 4"**

Answer (score 0):

```
    function break_string($string,  $group = 1, $delimeter = ' ', $reverse = true){
            $string_length = strlen($string);
            $new_string = [];
            while($string_length > 0){
                if($reverse) {
                    array_unshift($new_string, substr($string, $group*(-1)));
                }else{
                    array_unshift($new_string, substr($string, $group));
                }
                $string = substr($string, 0, ($string_length - $group));
                $string_length = $string_length - $group;
            }
            $result = '';
            foreach($new_string as $substr){
                $result.= $substr.$delimeter;
            }
            return trim($result, " ");
        }

$password="1bsdf4";
$result1 = break_string($password);
echo $result1;
Output: 1 b s d f 4;
$result2 = break_string($password, 2);
echo $result2;
Output: 1b sd f4.
```